# No data is set when wpf window is loaded?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a issue with passing information from one wpf window to another. For some reason when main window is loaded nothing is set in the label, I need to be able to keep the data in a string to use for anything (label not important but shows what I mean)?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public string MyData { get; set; }

    void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Content = MyData;

    }

public partial class LoginWindow : Window
{
    public LoginWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         string mytext = "blabla";
         MainWindow fromloginwindow = new MainWindow(); 
         fromloginwindow.Mydata = mytext;
    }
```

Or am I doing this the wrong way round?

**EDIT:**

Please do not go on a tangent about the label its unimportant I need to be able to get and set a string for use anywhere in the MainWindow. Also the string "mytext" is also irrelevant as obviously I will not be setting the string this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are running into an event lifecycle issue; the calls to the `Loaded` event happen pretty quickly and thus, the chance to set the text has passed. Instead, what you should do is either:

1) Bind the Property to the Label in the XAML

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
}

protected string _myData = string.Empty;
public string MyData
{
    get { return _myData; }
    set { _myData = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("MyData"); }
}

protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
{
    var methods = PropertyChanged;

    if(methods != null)
       methods(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
}

<Label Content="{Binding MyData}" />
```

2) Set the control text via another method (or inside the property declaration):

```
public void SetLabel(string text)
{
    label1.Content = text;
}

protected void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     MainWindow x = new MainWindow();
     x.SetLabel("blabla");
}
```

Comment: Good point, I always forget that interface. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Yes, theoretically it will work, but it will only work once, when the object is created. The complexity is there so that the UI updates whenever you set the value, and so you could set it in the future if you wanted.

Comment: see the problem with the above is the label isnt the important factor, its being able to use a string from one window in another. The label is just a quick and cheap way to show the data from the other window.

Comment: If it's a public property on the object, this it is available to any caller regardless of event state. If that is the case, then I'm not sure what the problem you're having is.

Answer (score 1):

The Loaded event occurs before you set MyData, change the code like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
   public MainWindow(string data)
   {
      MyData = data 
      InitializeComponent();        
   }
```

Comment: the label is non important its being able to have the string "Mydata" anywhere I want.

Comment: so as I see it unless label1 is set inside the get/set method you cant use the string MyData anywhere else in the application?

Comment: updating mydata will update the label, yes. If I understand you correctly the purpose of the label is to pass around a string value?

Comment: the label is completely irrelevant I want to be able to use the public string MyData anywhere in the Main Window (button click, window loaded where ever) i.e I just want to pass a string from login window to the main window and use that string where ever I like.

Comment: Nah that doesnt do anything either

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing the value to the second window through the window's constructor?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public MainWindow(string data)
        : this()
    {
        label1.Content = data;
    }
}

public partial class LoginWindow : Window
{
    public LoginWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         string mytext = "blabla";
         MainWindow fromloginwindow = new MainWindow(mytext); 
    }
}
```

Comment: can you make it a public string inside the main window? I want to be able to use the string anywhere in the MainWindow after its sent from the login window.